# Create a dictionary<string,string> from a semicolon separated string using linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a string like:

```
"some key:some value; john:doe;age:234"
```

I already wrote a method that takes this string and returns a:

```
Dictionary<string,string>
```

Was curious if someone could do this via linq?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that delimiters cannot appear in keys or values:

```
var dict = str.Split(';')
              .Select(s => s.Split(':'))
              .ToDictionary(a => a[0].Trim(), a => a[1].Trim()));
```

This is not the fastest way to do it, but it is the simplest.

You could also use a regex:

```
static readonly Regex parser = new Regex(@"([^:]):([^;])");

var dict = parser.GetMatches(str)
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[0].Value.Trim(), 
                               m => m.Groups[0].Value.Trim()
                 );
```

Comment: Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), and same with  the second split might help

Comment: @Hatchet: Yes; that would allow for a trailing `;`